# 3 month rolling average with missing months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been reading the related questions here, and so far the solutions require that there are no missing months. Would love to get some help on what I can do if there are missing months?

For example, I'd like to calculate the 3 month rolling average of orders per item. If there is a missing month for an item, the calculation assumes that the number of orders for that item for that month is 0. If there are fewer than three months left, the rolling average isn't so important (it can be null or otherwise).

```
MONTH   | ITEM | ORDERS | ROLLING_AVG
2021-04 | A    | 5      |  3.33
2021-04 | B    | 4      |  3
2021-03 | A    | 3      |  1.66
2021-03 | B    | 5      |  null
2021-02 | A    | 2      |  null
2021-01 | B    | 2      |  null
```

Big thanks in advance!

Also, is there a way to "add" the missing month rows without using a cross join with a list of items? For example if I have 10 million items, the cross join takes quite a while to execute.

Comment: Fill in the missing months?  You don't need a row to exist to make the rolling average calculation work, but if you want a month to appear in the results, that month has to exist as a row ***somewhere***.  I recommend a calendar table and then using `calendar CROSS JOIN item_table LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.month = calendar.month AND orders.item = item_table.item`

Comment: Thanks for the guide! I realised what my mistake was -- I was referencing the original table in the window function instead of the calendar table and the item table, as such I couldn't get the resulting aggregation that I wanted.

Comment: Thats an example of why you should Always include the SQL you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `range` window frame -- and some conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(month) over (partition by item) <= month - interval '2 month'
             then sum(orders) over (partition by item
                                    order by month
                                    range between interval '2 month' preceding and current row
                                   ) / 3.0
        end) as rolling_average
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7826ce7222812fb628362f2af575a626) is a db<>fiddle.  The results are slightly different from what is in your question, because there is not enough info for A in 2021-03 but there is enough for B in 2021-03.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I never knew we could use range between a time interval and a row. Learnt something new today. This is so much faster than creating additional tables for cross joins.